# image.asInlineImage().getBlob() hangs for ever

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-apps-script-addon

The following new problem occurs in a Google-Docs Add-On script, I believe without having changed the script nor the source document.

Since this afternoon, the following code started hanging at line: `var blob = sourceImage.asInlineImage().getBlob()`. The logger correctly logs the image width and height, but never logs 'blobbed'.

```
var sourceImage = cell.getChild(m).getChild(0);
var imageHeight = sourceImage.getHeight();
var imageWidth = sourceImage.getWidth();
Logger.log('imageWidth:' + imageWidth + ', imageHeight:' + imageHeight);
var blob = sourceImage.asInlineImage().getBlob();
Logger.log('blobbed');
```

I tried to completely replace the source image with a new image, no resize, no clipping. This resulted in correct new width and height output in the log, but again the code never gets past the getBlob() line, no exceptions are being logged (both Stackdriver error reporting and Stackdriver logging are empty). The same problem happens with other source documents.

The source documents are in a shared Drive. Up until about a week ago, the script was working. Something to do with permissions? Something changed in the API? Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

While preparing a minimal complete verifiable example, I discovered the problem was in `element.copy()`. The script was copying elements from one page to the other. The code first did a copy, then traversed the children of the copy. Apparently, `element.copy()` copies all children, but if one of the children contains an image, you can not use getBlob() on the copied image.

Instead of:

```
var element = templateBody.getChild(i).copy();
...
newParagraph = target.appendParagraph(element)
...
newTable = body.appendTable(element);
```

use:

```
var element = templateBody.getChild(i);
...
newParagraph = target.appendParagraph(element.copy())
...
newTable = body.appendTable(element.copy());
```

Not using element.copy(), you can now use getBlob() on a subelement of an element of type table:

```
element.getChild(j).getCell(k).getChild(m).getChild(0).asInlineImage().getBlob();
```

It remains unclear why the old version of the code worked until last week or so.